# Why does my array spiral off

Tags: modifiers

I've added an empty axis which I'm trying to use as the Object offset in the Array modifier to evenly position the handle details around the handle on this Darth Vader lightsaber hilt, however the array spirals off strangely.
I can't get them around the handle neatly. [image].

Comment: Did you apply the scale of the object?

Comment: This is most likely your problem: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14422/array-modifier-is-scaling-objects-for-seemingly-no-reason

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: I Applied Rotation and Scale to the Object I'm arraying and I've almost got the position correct, to get even spacing I rotated the Empty by hitting  r y = 360/8. But the circumference is a little too high, can this be edited?

Comment: By the looks of your screenshot, it seems that your origin is already out of plane with your empty. Try getting your objects origin in line with that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the method I've used to solve my issue, select the object you want to array, hit <kbd>Shift + S</kbd> to snap the 3D cursor to the selected object, create an empty on said object (make sure rotation and scale are ticked for an even and proportional array), select the object add the array modifier, untick relative offset instead use object offset using the empty just placed and apply how many counts you need.
To evenly space the array I selected the empty hit <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>360</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>, which divided 360 degrees into 8 parts (which was my array count) on the Y axis.
To make small adjustments I selected the object in edit mode and positioned it slightly as well as making minor adjustments to the empty.

[image]